# How to get the equivalent LINENO variable content in loaded/exec file script under AIX versions of KSH (not 93)

Tags: debugging, ksh, aix

(under KSH, not KSH93) i use `export PS4='+Line: ${LINENO}: ';set -vx` line in script for debug and tracing.

it's enough for most of the time but it "fail" when the script is loading another script with `. OtherFile`. It still trace but the variable LINENO stay stuck on the line calling the sub script.

Is there a way to change this behaviour for the sub script (restarting the count to 0 for this will be perfect)

i try to reput the line into the subscript but it doesn't change.

Example

```
export PS4='+Line: ${LINENO}: ';set -vx
echo "main"
echo "echo 'slave 1'" > /tmp/slave.txt
echo "echo 'slave 2'" >> /tmp/slave.txt
. /tmp/slave.txt
```

return stuck on line 5

```
...
+Line: 4: echo echo 'slave 2'
+Line: 4: 1>> /tmp/slave.txt
. /tmp/slave.txt
+Line: 5: . /tmp/slave.txt
+Line: 5: echo slave 1
slave 1
+Line: 5: echo slave 2
slave 2
...
```

Comment: I know you ask for line number, not which command. Perhaps this approach helps : `mycommand_no=1
export PS4='+Command: $((mycommand_no++)): ';set -vx`.

Comment: indeed, i also try something like this, the equivalent of linux 'caller'. thanks for the idea

Answer (score 2):

As your comment and a tag on the question suggest, you running a very old version of ksh, e.g. AIX ksh.

If you use some version of ksh93, `$LINENO` does update. So two obvious possibilities are:

- register a bug report for AIX ksh
- have a private version of ksh93 around that you can swap in when you need it

As for ksh93, there are other variables in `.sh` structured variables like `.sh.file`

Here is an example:

```
export PS4='file ${.sh.file}, line $LINENO '
$ ksh -x /etc/profile
file /etc/profile, line 4 [ $'$? $(printf %(%H:%M:%S)T) ${USER}@$(hostname):${PWD} [$SHLVL,${.sh.subshell},k] \n\\$ ' ]
file /etc/profile, line 5 [ '' ]
file /etc/profile, line 12 id -u
file /etc/profile, line 12 [ 1000 -eq 0 ]
file /etc/profile, line 15 PS1='$ '
file /etc/profile, line 20 [ -d /etc/profile.d ]
file /etc/profile, line 22 [ -r /etc/profile.d/appmenu-qt5.sh ]
file /etc/profile, line 23 . /etc/profile.d/appmenu-qt5.sh
file /etc/profile.d/appmenu-qt5.sh, line 1 QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=appmenu-qt5
file /etc/profile.d/appmenu-qt5.sh, line 1 export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME
file /etc/profile, line 22 [ -r /etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh ]
file /etc/profile, line 23 . /etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh
fi
```

You seem to imply that there is *one* "KSH" instead of many: if only there is a magical way to get this done in one of them, it would be applicable to your AIX ksh.l. So let me elaborate...

AT&T sold or licensed the rights to ksh to IBM, HP, DEC and other companies which allowed them in turn to modify and redistribute the modified code as ksh. And indeed those companies (and others) did do that, leaving a big problem if you were David Korn and wanted to make improvements or fix bugs across the board.

That problem was one of the things that David Korn was trying to address with ksh93 - getting back control of a single code base whereby old bugs could be fixed and new features added.

And then  there is the [POSIX Shell Command Standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). When it comes to `LINENO`, it suggests that what you experience may be a bug, but is a little bit vague here and suggests `LINENO` might be optional:

> **LINENO** Set by the shell to a decimal number representing the current sequential line number (numbered starting with 1) within a
>   script or function before it executes each command. If the user unsets
>   or resets LINENO, the variable may lose its special meaning for the
>   life of the shell. If the shell is not currently executing a script or
>   function, the value of LINENO is unspecified. This volume of
>   POSIX.1-2017 specifies the effects of the variable only for systems
>   supporting the User Portability Utilities option.

Comment: right, most of my customer still use the AIX ksh even if ksh93 is often available and i have to work with :-(

Comment: Ok. Then I guess you should specify that in your question. And then your question becomes, "in AIX versions of ksh, how to work around the fact that LINENO doesn't perform the way it does in ksh93".

Comment: Submitted an edit to the title to mention "AIX versions of ksh"